# How to copy the values of an object into the keys of another object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have 2 Objects.

Object1:

```
      {
         "a": "XXXXX",
         "b": "YYYYY",
         "c": "ZZZZZ"
      }
```

and Object2:

```
    {
        "a": "KKKKK",
        "b": "LLLLL",
        "c": "MMMMM"
    }
```

both have the same length and same keys at the same index, but different values.

Result should be:

```
    {
        "XXXXX": "KKKKK",
        "YYYYY": "LLLLL",
        "ZZZZZ": "MMMMM"
    }
```

i've tried:

```
    for (let el in Object2){
      el = Object1[el]      
    }
```

but its not working. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Keys don't have an "index". You cannot changed a property name, but you can delete a property you don't want and add a new property that you do want.

Comment: Note that a fully generic solution won't be possible as objects are not meant to be used for anything relying on order. Integer keys, for example, will throw a wrench in any solution. Better to use an array or `Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const x = {
   "a": "XXXXX",
   "b": "YYYYY",
   "c": "ZZZZZ"
}

const y = {
  "a": "KKKKK",
  "b": "LLLLL",
  "c": "MMMMM"
} 

const z = Object.keys(x).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[x[key]] = y[key]
  return acc
},{})

console.log(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Object.keys` to iterate over the keys of the first object and use its values as the keys for the `result` object:

```js
const obj1 = {
         "a": "XXXXX",
         "b": "YYYYY",
         "c": "ZZZZZ"
      }
const obj2 = {
        "a": "KKKKK",
        "b": "LLLLL",
        "c": "MMMMM"
    } 
const result = Object.keys(obj1).reduce((acc, ele, idx) => {
  acc[obj1[ele]] = obj2[ele];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Object.assign` with `Object.values`:

```js
var obj1 = {
  "a": "XXXXX",
  "b": "YYYYY",
  "c": "ZZZZZ"
};

var obj2 = {
  "a": "KKKKK",
  "b": "LLLLL",
  "c": "MMMMM"
};

var obj3 = Object.assign(...Object.values(obj1).map((k, i) => ({[k]: Object.values(obj2)[i]})));

console.log(obj3);
```

Or, use a `forEach`:

```js
var obj1 = {
  "a": "XXXXX",
  "b": "YYYYY",
  "c": "ZZZZZ"
};

var obj2 = {
  "a": "KKKKK",
  "b": "LLLLL",
  "c": "MMMMM"
};

var obj3 = {};

Object.values(obj1).forEach((key, i) => obj3[key] = Object.values(obj2)[i]);

console.log(obj3);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.Values` + `reduce` something  like this:

```js
const a = {
  "a": "XXXXX",
  "b": "YYYYY",
  "c": "ZZZZZ"
}


const b = {
  "a": "KKKKK",
  "b": "LLLLL",
  "c": "MMMMM"
}

var res = Object.values(a).reduce((newObject, value, index) => {
  newObject[value] = Object.values(b)[index]
  return newObject;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Object.entries` to iterate over the keys of the first object and use its values as the keys for the `result` object:

```js
const obj1 = {
         "a": "XXXXX",
         "b": "YYYYY",
         "c": "ZZZZZ"
      }
const obj2 = {
        "a": "KKKKK",
        "b": "LLLLL",
        "c": "MMMMM"
    } 
const result = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((acc, ele) => {
  acc[ele[1]] = obj2[ele[0]];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the keys and set the key and value of the output object based on the value in the input objects

```js
const o1 = { a: "XXXXX", b: "YYYYY", c: "ZZZZZ" },
      o2 = { a: "KKKKK", b: "LLLLL", c: "MMMMM" },
      output = {};

for (let key in o1)
  output[o1[key]] = o2[key]

console.log(output)
```